Colcon build CMake error for gz_ros2_control: gz_sim_vendor not found
I am trying to build $ colcon build --mixin release the moveit2_tutorials repo using their Getting started guide, however I am faced with this CMake error (full console output gist link):
--- stderr: gz_ros2_control                                            
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:27 (find_package):
  By not providing "Findgz_sim_vendor.cmake" in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH this
  project has asked CMake to find a package configuration file provided by
  "gz_sim_vendor", but CMake did not find one.

  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "gz_sim_vendor"
  with any of the following names:

    gz_sim_vendorConfig.cmake
    gz_sim_vendor-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "gz_sim_vendor" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
  "gz_sim_vendor_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If
  "gz_sim_vendor" provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it
  has been installed.


---
Failed   <<< gz_ros2_control [3.15s, exited with code 1]

I have created a github issue for this in the moveit2_tutorials repo on github and tried updating and upgrading multiple times. I also installed gazebo following this tutorial.

Delete the gz_ros1_control package from the src directory before performing colcon
